# Knockout.js initial load is not firing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to do some cascading dropdowns using Knockout.js  Right after I define the view model, I have the following code, but the $.getJSON is not firing up.  Please help.  Is this the right way to do cascade dropdown?  Thanks.

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://my.comapny/webapi/facility/',
      null, function (response) {
          viewModel.facilities(response);
      });

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

Here is the cshtml:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        function vm() {
            var self = this;

            self.facility = ko.observable();
            self.facilities = ko.observableArray();
            self.service = ko.observable();
            self.services = ko.observableArray();
            self.role = ko.observable();
            self.roles = ko.observableArray();
            self.result = ko.observable();

            self.facilitySelect = ko.computed({
                read: self.facility,
                write: function (facility) {
                    self.facility(facility);
                    $.getJSON('http://my.comapny/webapi/service/' + self.facility.value,
                        null, function (response) {
                            self.services(response);
                        });
                },
                owner: self
            });
            self.serviceSelect = ko.computed({
                read: self.service,
                write: function (service) {
                    self.service(service);
                    $.getJSON('http://my.comapny/webapi/role' +
                        '?facilityId=' + self.facility.value + '&serviceId=' + self.service.value,
                               null, function (response) {
                                   self.roles(response);
                               });
                },
                owner: self
            });
            self.result = ko.computed(function () {
                var result = '';
                result += self.facility() != undefined ? 'Facility: ' + self.facility().text + ', ' : '';
                result += self.service() != undefined ? 'Service: ' + self.service().text + ', ' : '';
                result += self.role() != undefined ? 'Role: ' + self.role().text : '';
                return result;
            }, self);



        }
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON('http://my.comapny/webapi/facility/',
              null, function (response) {
                  vm.facilities(response);
              });

            ko.applyBindings(new vm());
        });
    </script>
}


<h1>Knockout js cascading dropdown example</h1>
<select data-bind="options: facilities, optionsCaption: 'Choose facility...',
    optionsValue: function (item) { return item.value; },
    optionsText: function (item) { return item.text; }, value: facilitySelect,
    valueUpdate: 'change'"
    id="facility" name="facility">
</select>
<select data-bind="options: services, optionsCaption: 'Choose service...',
    optionsValue: function (item) { return item.value; },
    optionsText: function (item) { return item.text; }, value: serviceSelect,
    valueUpdate: 'change'"
    id="service" name="service">
</select>
<select data-bind="options: roles, optionsCaption: 'Choose role...',
    optionsValue: function (item) { return item.value; },
    optionsText: function (item) { return item.text; }, value: role,
    valueUpdate: 'change'"
    id="role" name="role">
</select>
<span data-bind="text: result"></span>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to only the *relevant* bits, and add your research / attempts to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you misspell your url?

Is this: `http://my.comapny/webapi/facility/`

Supposed to be this: `http://my.company/webapi/facility/`

I'd recommend renaming your constructor function from `vm` to `ViewModel` as I believe that's causing you confusion into thinking that `vm` is an instance of your ViewModel instead of it being the constructor function.

```
function ViewModel () { ... }
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
// Later...
vm.facilities(response);
```